# Save plotly plots in a single pdf

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

My code is generating poorly plots (around 100).
This needs to be saved in a single pdf file.

```
for i in range(len(stats_ETF.columns)):
    fig2 = px.scatter(stats_ETF, x = 'Date', y = stats_ETF.columns[i+1])
    fig2.show()
```

fig 2 has each of those plots.
Can someone help on how all plots can be saved in a single pdf?

Comment: Look into subplots and then place the show() command outside the loop (to populate all subplots inside the loop first, and when that's done display them with show).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can arrive at following solution using these articles/documentation:

- [Subplots in Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/subplots/)
- [plotly.io: low-level interface for displaying, reading and writing figures](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.io.write_image.html#plotly.io.write_image)

You need to install: `pip install kaleido`

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go

stats_ETF = pd.DataFrame({
    "Date": ["2022-01-01", "2022-02-01", "2022-03-01", "2022-04-01", "2022-01-05"],
    "Earnings": [250, 220, 250, 230, 250],
    "Expenses": [200, 180, 210, 190, 220],
    "Earnings_1": [250, 220, 250, 230, 250],
    "Expenses_1": [200, 180, 210, 190, 220],
    "Earnings_2": [250, 220, 250, 230, 250],
    "Expenses_2": [200, 180, 210, 190, 220],
    "Earnings_3": [250, 220, 250, 230, 250],
    "Expenses_3": [200, 180, 210, 190, 220],
    "Earnings_4": [250, 220, 250, 230, 250],
    "Expenses_4": [200, 180, 210, 190, 220],
    })

fig = make_subplots(rows=len(stats_ETF.columns)-1, cols=1)

for i in range(1, len(stats_ETF.columns)):
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(x=stats_ETF["Date"], y=stats_ETF[stats_ETF.columns[i]]),
        row=i, col=1
    )    

fig.update_layout(height=200*len(stats_ETF.columns), width=800, title_text="Multiple Subplots")
# fig.show()
pio.write_image(fig, "stats_plots.pdf", format="pdf", engine="kaleido")
```

This generates a PDF with all plots in one page.

Comment: Thanks. This works. Is it possible to change the bubbles into star or something?